# Reverse Dependency Service

Tags: xamarin, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms Project. I have used Dependency Service to call the Platform specific method to fire a local notification on Android and a Alert on iOS.
My problem is now, how to handle an action on both notification(android) and alert(iOS). Is it possible to call a method of the shared project from the android or iOS project?

Do I need another approach? Does someone know what I have to do?

Just for clarification, I know how the ordinary dependency services works i.e. Call a method on android or iOS from the shared project!

Comment: the platform projects should have a direct reference to the shared project, so they can directly call code in the shared project.  Alternatively, you can use MessagingCenter to send a message from the platform project and subscribe to it in the shared project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I had a similar scenario on my app. If you want to push something from your platform methods to your PCL you would need to make use of call backs and event delegates.

In Interface PCL:

```
    event OnMessageHandlerCallback OnMessageEvent;
    event OnErrorHandlerCallBack OnErrorEvent;
```

In Platform specific Class inheriting interface:

```
 private OnMessageHandlerCallback callback = null;
    private OnErrorHandlerCallBack errorCallBack = null;

    public event OnMessageHandlerCallback OnMessageEvent;

    public event OnErrorHandlerCallBack OnErrorEvent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just calling the method from your native project...? No special patterns necessary. The native iOS and Android projects have a direct reference to your shared project, so it can call the method directly.